# How to select elements that do not have a specific ancestor element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Have a look at this example :

```
<div id="root" class="box">
    <div class="box">
        <input letter="A"></input>
        <input letter="B"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="subroot" class="box">
        <div class="useless_class">
            <input letter="B"></input>
            <div class="useless_class">
                <input letter="D"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <input letter="F"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input letter="E"></input>
</div>
```

I need a jQuery selector to have the input which do not have an ancestor element with class `.box`.

This is the desired result:

```
input:
    searchInputsInElement($("#root"))
output:
    <input letter="E"></input>

input:
    searchInputsInElement($("#subroot"))
output:
    <input letter="B"></input>
    <input letter="D"></input>
```

The final objective is to call the `theSuperFunction` recursively.

 ###############################################################################
 # SOLVED ######################################################################
 ###############################################################################

Thanks to @Shubanker, I made [this](https://codepen.io/antoineduval/pen/EGJVLV) final code (have a look at the `console.log` result).

Comment: `#root.box > input` and `#subroot.box  input` .. `>` means direct child

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef The second selector you've specified won't match any elements, because there are no `input` elements that are direct descendants of `#subroot`.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, Thanks, but I need it to works with infinite dom between target and root. I'll not do `#root.box > .abc > .dev > .mdr > ... > input` for each possibilities :/

Comment: @BenM yes I remove the `>` from the second selector .. thanks

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, Look at my edit plz, in your exemple, the second one will return the F input too.

Comment: @WebIsOur so now you need the B and D but not F which inside the `.box` class??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, Yes :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use JQuery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter according to your desired result and [parentsUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) to search for parent with class `'box'` within selector.

```
function theSuprFunction($selector){
   return $selector.find('input').filter(function(){
       return $(this).parentsUntil($selector,'.box').length===0 
   });
}
```

Also you can use `.filter()` with `.parent()` and `hasClass`

```js
theSuprFunction($('#root'));

function theSuprFunction($selector){
   $selector.find('input').filter(function(){
       return !$(this).not($selector.find('> input')).parent().hasClass('box');
   }).css('background' , 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" class="box">
    <div class="box">
        <input value="A" letter="A"/>
        <input value="B" letter="B"/>
    </div>
    <div id="subroot" class="box">
        <div class="useless_class">
            <input value="B" letter="B"/>
            <div class="useless_class">
                <input value="D" letter="D"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <input value="F" letter="F"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input value="E" letter="E"/>
</div>
```

> **Note:** `.not($selector.find('> input'))` will extract the `#root` input while it has a `.box` class

Comment: if you don't mind .. I edited your answer with my attempt .. no need to add another answer .. if you see its useless you can remove it .. Thanks

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - thanks for the input, your solution checks for input whose parent is not `.box` unless parent is given selector itself, however op requirement is to check through all the parents until selector-1 level and omit input if any of parent has `.box` as clearly shown in desired results, running your snippet mismatches the desired result by OP.

Comment: I got your point @Shubanker and I tested your code and my code and I know exactly what you're saying .. I added my code because I understood from OP comments that he needs to select the three inputs .. maybe I misunderstood that .. But till now there is no reply from the OP to let's know which one is works for him .. I was intended to delete my code but let's wait and see if the OP reply :-) .. you're free to delete/edit my code anytime as you like :-) .. Have a great day :-)